# Magento translation in custom extension

Tags: localisation, helper

I would like to use translations from my own extension. I've created `helper` and translation file in different locales. But Magento shown me translation from Mage_ locale
There is my code:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <myextension_base>
            <class>Myextension_Base_Helper</class>
        </myextension_base>
    </helpers>
```

under global in `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Myextension_Base>
                <files>
                    <default>Myextension_Base.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Myextension_Base>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

in template `Mage::helper('myextension_base')->__('Cart')`

I've created files in `en_US` and `de_DE`

Where I do something wrong?

UPD Looks like Mage_ translations has priority or my translation placed after Mage_ translations

Comment: make your module depend on the checkout module. this way it will be loaded after the core one and (most probably) it will override the core translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.
Your module should depend on `Mage_Checkout`.
This way it will be loaded after it and it will override the translations.
This can be done by making the file `app/etc/modules/Myextension_Base.xml` look like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myextension_Base>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout>
            </depends>
        </Myextension_Base>
    </modules>
</config>
```